# How can I keep the referer in a Wordpress function after a redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have these 2 functions in my site:

```
add_action('get_header', 'my_referrer_redirect');

function my_referrer_redirect () {

    if( strpos( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?tbl=" ) !== false ){

        $honey = (int) filter_var(get_query_var('tbl'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        wp_redirect( 'https://my-home.com/t'.$honey.'?table='.$honey);

            exit;
    }
}

add_action('get_header', 'my_referrer_check');

function my_referrer_check () {

    if( strpos( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "t" ) !== false ){

        $referer = wp_get_referer();

        if ( strpos( $referer, "tbl" ) == false ) {

            wp_redirect( 'http://google.com' );

            exit;

            }
        }
}
```

The first one redirects to another page IF the string "?tbl=" is found in the url. It uses the value of the "tbl" parameter to redirect to another page.

The second one checks this: if the url contains "t", then check the referer. If the referer has the string "tbl" in its URL then do nothing, if it doesn't, redirect to google.

Problem is that it seems like the referer is lost after the first redirection, because the second function always redirects to google. If the second function is standalone, without the first one, it works correctly (for example if I get to that page using a button), but I need both functions to work. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: What is the the value of `$referer` before redirect to google?

Comment: The value of `$referer` should be https://my-home.com/?tbl={number from 1 to 51}, aka the page that triggers the first function.
I say "should" because it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you use a session to store the value in between? I'm not sure I followed the logic of the redirection. You can't redirect twice, is `my-home.com` the domain of your site?

Comment: no my-home.com was just an example, however I'm trying with sessions and session variables and it seems to be working! I save the first referer in a variable in the first function and call it on the second function, and it works. So thank you, just need to understand how to close sessions when I want.